# Best strategy to run multiple telegram bots which can be activated on the fly on the same server

Tags: python, nginx, telegram, python-telegram-bot

My intention is to create a dynamic way to launch a new telegram bot using python-telegram-bot. In this moment I run one bot which is starting a webhook with a specific `TOKEN` and `PORT`.
On a trigger, which I will write, I want a new telegram bot with a new webhook to be started on a specific port using the TOKEN of the telegram bot.

I have the following setup:

- Droplet on DigitalOcean
- Certificates from Let's encrypt
- NGINX as a proxy (not running as a docker container, yet)
- In NGINX, each bot will have it's own file which is included in the module nginx configuration and each file contains `location /TOKEN ...` and the `proxy pass`.

Therefore, from the NGINX perspective, I can create another file with a new bot with token and is automatically included in NGINX.
On the application side, I am have some doubts how to proceed on the python side.

What would be the best method to launch a new telegram bot on-the-fly?
Is an idea to run each bot in a docker container and each container is listening to a webhook, so ne telegram bot? Or there is another option which allows me to listen on a "generic" webhook and based on token/chat id I can decide what to do with the input which I receive.